# Merge more than two rows into one row and place right data into right column

Tags: sql, sql-server

First of I'm sorry if the question heading seems confusing to you guys but let me show you what I want.

Let's say I have a table called **topic**.

```
Topic_ID | Parent_Topic_ID | Topic_Text           | lang_culture
---------|-----------------|----------------------|--------------
    1    |       0         | Newton's Law         |   en-US
    2    |       1         | First Law            |   en-US
```

Now I have another table named **translated_topic** where the same topic is stored in different languages

```
Topic_ID | text                | lang_culture
---------|-------------------- |--------------
   1     | न्यूटन का नियम        |   hi-IN
   1     | loi de newton       |   fr-FR

   2     | पहला कानून           |  hi-IN
   2     | Première loi        |  fr-FR
```

Now, I want the show output like this...

```
Topic_ID | Topic_Text         | lang_culture | hi-In            | fr-FR     
---------|--------------------|--------------|------------------ |-------------
    1    |    Newton's Law    |en-US         | न्यूटन का नियम      | loi de newton
    2    |    First Law       | en-US        | पहला कानून         |Première loi
```

How can I achieve this output in SQL-server?

What I am getting now,

```
 SELECT td.topic_id,
           td.Topic_Text AS MainText,
           td.lang_culture,
           tt.text,
           tt.lang_culture
    FROM dbo.topic td
        LEFT JOIN dbo.translated_topic tt
            ON td.topic_id = tt.topic_id;
```

But after that don't know how to get my desired result?

Comment: Sir, I followed this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server but could not able to figure out how to write it properly. If someone could help me then it will be much nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can you PIVOT as below-

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT A.Topic_ID,A.Parent_Topic_ID,A.Topic_Text,A.lang_culture lang_culture,B.lang_culture B,B.text
    FROM Table1 A
    INNER JOIN Table2 B ON A.Topic_ID = B.Topic_ID
)P 
PIVOT
(
    MAX(text)
    FOR B IN ([hi-IN],[fr-FR])
) PVT
```